# Como definir o formato da imagem ao salvar o arquivo usando “html2canvas”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

Estou usando o canvas2image.js para transformar uma div em uma imagem, tudo funciona, o problema, preciso definir um formato para a imagem no momento de salvar, sem isso ela fica sem um formato válido.

Exemplo:

```html
<link href="~/Content/css/CarimboBanner.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/ContentAdmin/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/canvas2image.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/CarimboImagens.js"></script>


<div class="carimbo-foto">
<img src="http://img.vmessages.com/en/funny/35.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="carimbo" alt="" width="90" height="98">
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/bandeira-horizontal-de-cloudscape-43923748.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="banner" alt="" width="560" height="315">
<img src="http://cdnqrcgde.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/jpeg.jpg" class="img-responsive" id="qrcode" alt="" width="80" height="80">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        html2canvas($(".carimbo-foto"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                //$(".main-footer").append(canvas);
                // Clean up
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser resolvido fazendo uma adaptação na função `saveFile` do JavaScript `Canvas2Image`.

A ideia é criar um elemento `anchor` via JS, setar o `toDataURL()` e o nome do arquivo juntamente com sua extensão e executar o download.

Edite seu arquivo `canvas2image.js`, procure por `saveFile` e altere de acordo com o código a seguir:

```
function saveFile (strData) {
    //document.location.href = strData;
    downloadURI(strData,"img.png");
}

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```